# How to bring an element to the front and put it back later in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a graph in d3, that performs multitude of animations on different events. For one of those, I had to bring selected element to the front, which I did using following bit:

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });
};
```

Thing is, after all the code I needed it in the front is performed, I want to put that element back *exactly* where I took it from. So, If an element had an `index` of 1 (out of 7 elements available), then I moved it to front (which changed the index to 6), now I want to set the `index` back to 1.

I tried putting it at the bottom of index array already (asigning it index 0), but it does not suit my needs.

Also, I'm willing to get rid of `moveToFront()` prototype, if there's any better way to accomplish what I want, that's just the best way I could find for now.

Comment: What's the version? D3 v3 or v4?

Comment: Using v4 you could simply write `selection.raise()` and `selection.lower()`, but it'd put the element at the bottom of the selection, not at its previous position.

Comment: That's the thing. I need to put it back exactly where I took it from. Besides, since whole thing was designed in V3, I would need to redesign whole graph. And we don't want that, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I have an idea, that you can build on top of this code of Scott Murray: http://bl.ocks.org/alignedleft/9612839. Create a duplicate and leave the original element where it is. Set the original element opacity to 0, and bring the duplicate to front. Then, when you want revert to the initial situation, delete de duplicate (or make its opacity 0) and set the original element opacity to 1.

Comment: Oh. Oh. Oooooh. Okay. It actually might work. Will try.

Comment: Point a <use> element at the original.

Comment: Agree with @RobertLongson on SVG `<use>`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use